# Deserialization of JSON.Net returns 'null'

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am using JSON.Net to Deserialize a JSON string. The JSON string is

```
string testJson = @"{
                    ""Fruits"": {
                        ""Apple"": {
                            ""color"": ""red"",
                            ""size"": ""round""                               
                        },
                        ""Orange"": {
                            ""Properties"": {
                                ""color"": ""red"",
                                ""size"": ""round"" 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }";
```

and my code is

```
public class Fruits
{
    public Apple apple { get; set; }
    public Orange orange { get; set; }
}

public class Apple
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }            
}

public class Orange
{
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string color { get; set; }
    public string size { get; set; }   
}
```

I am trying to Deserialize this with the following code

```
Fruits result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fruits>(testJson);
```

I have a problem in my **result** that **Fruits** with **Apple** and **Orange** has `null` instead of their **Properties** , **color** , **size**.

Comment: The problem is that the outermost `{ ... }` bracers correspond to your `Fruits` type, and `Fruits` does not contain a property named `Fruits`. Try creating a container type, containing a `Fruits` property, and deserialize that.

Comment: Or go the other way and serialise something to JSON to understand the correct format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you can't change the json, you need to create a new `FruitsWrapper` class that has a `Fruits` property

```
public class FruitsWrapper
{
    public Fruits Fruits { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize the json into an instance of `FruitsWrapper` instead of `Fruits`

```
FruitsWrapper result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FruitsWrapper>(testJson);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nQitSD

Answer (score 2):

the JSON string should be:

```
string testJson = @"{ 
                        ""Apple"": {
                            ""color"": ""red"",
                            ""size"": ""round""},
                        ""Orange"": { 
                            ""Properties"": {
                                ""color"": ""red"",
                                ""size"": ""round"" }
                                }
                    }";
```

to be deserialized with your class

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the outermost bracers in your Json corresponds to the type you're trying to deserialize.

So this:

```
string testJson = @"{
                      ""Fruits"": { ... }
                    }";
```

Corresponds to Fruits since that's what you're trying to deserialize.

```
string testJson = @"{
                      ""Fruits"": { ... }
                        ^--+-^
                           |
                           +-- this is assumed to be a property of this --+
                                                                          |
                                                 +------------------------+
                                                 |
                                              v--+-v
Fruits result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fruits>(testJson);
```

However, the `Fruits` type does not have a property named `Fruits` and thus nothing is deserialized.

If the Json cannot be changed, you need to create a container type that you deserialize instead, like this:

```
public class Container
{
    public Fruits Fruits { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can deserialize that:

```
Container result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(testJson);
```

Answer (score 0):

You JSON string isn't correct (as others have pointed out) but I'm adding this to assist you with finding the correct format. Given you have a `fruit` object like this:

```
var fruit = new Fruits
{
    apple = new Apple { color = "red", size = "massive" },
    orange = new Orange { properties = new Properties { color = "orange", size = "mediumish" } }
};
```

You can then serialise this to JSON:

```
var testJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fruit);
```

And now you can see the serialised output will look like this: (slightly formatted)

```
{"apple":
    {"color":"red","size":"massive"},
 "orange":
    {"properties":
        {"color":"orange","size":"mediumish"}}}
```

And this will easily deserialise back into your object:

```
fruit = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Fruits>(testJson);
```