# Why is my class object empty after running JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<class>(string)?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialize a JSON string into a large object; I'm using Angular to send my data to a controller. Data is present and correct when it arrives in the controller, but after deserialization, it's null. I've looked at some questions already, like this one here:

[Deserialization of JSON.Net returns 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128538/deserialization-of-json-net-returns-null)

Based on the answer to the question above, and the comment from the user who wrote the question, my code should work, but it doesn't.

Here's my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public OnlineOrderValidation Post(HttpRequestMessage request) 
{
            Task<string> result = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var json = result.Result;
            OnlineOrder order = new OnlineOrder();
            order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OnlineOrder>(json);

            // Save first
            _orderFacade.UpdateCurrentOrder(CacheStore, order);

            var validation = _orderFacade.ValidateOrder(order);

            return validation;
}
```

The OnlineOrder class should accept all of the data from JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json), but the values are either 0, null, or false. 
I've tried DeserializeAnonymousType(string json, T anonObject) and JavasScriptSerializer.Deserialize(string data) as well, and they both yield an empty OnlineOrder object with null values.

I've also tried passing the object to the controller like this:

```
public OnlineOrderValidation Post([FromBody]string ooJson)
{
    var order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OnlineOrder>(ooJson);
    //work with order object...
}
```

and like this

```
public OnlineOrderValidation Post([FromUri]string ooJson)
{
    var order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OnlineOrder>(ooJson);
    //work with order object...
}
```

I wonder if the problem lies with 'ReadAsStringAsync()'. I noticed that it spits out each property on OnlineOrder out of order. The async part of this method must add each field/value pair as it finishes parsing the string, and since the first field in result doesn't match the first field on the OnlineOrder object, maybe JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() just stops execution.

Do I need to make a wrapper class for OnlineOrder and deserialize to that? Do I need to reorder the fields in my 'result' object before deserializing? Is there something else I'm doing wrong? Thanks all!

**EDIT:** Here is my JSON, as requested. The actual object is much larger than this, but you get the idea. The JSON string has valid data, but is either nulled or zeroed out after deserialization.

```
{"isTMIOfferEligible":false,
"tmiOfferCode":null,
"tmiUpgradeOfferCode":null,
"id":"a34mdxdivt0svmu1okucidbi",
"accountNumber":"111111111",
"transferAccountNumber":"222222222",
"serviceAddress":
    {"address":"3922 N STREET AVE",
    "addressLine":"3901 N STREET AVE",
    "suite":"SYNCRD",
    "city":"SOOFOO",
    "state":"SD",
    "zip":"57000",
    "franchise":"111",
    "market":"1        "},
"transferAddress":
    {"disconnectDate":null,
    "transferFromAddress":
        {"address":"1234 SOME PLACE",
        "addressLine":"1234 SOME PLACE",
        "suite":"SYNCRD",
        "city":"SOOFOO",
        "state":"SD",
        "zip":"57000",
        "franchise":"123",
        "market":"Z         "
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**
I've updated my code to deserialize the JSON string from a custom, async method, and instantiate OnlineOrder when it's assigned:

```
            try
        {
            var orderTask = ReadStringAsynchronously(request);
            OnlineOrder order = orderTask.Result;

            //work with order object
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { //...}

        private async Task<OnlineOrder> ReadStringAsynchronously(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            var json = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            OnlineOrder orderAsync = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OnlineOrder>(json);
            return orderAsync;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error occurred while reading string asynchronously.");
        }
    }
```

The order object on the task is still null.

Comment: Well we can't see your JSON or your `OnlineOrder` class, which makes it very hard to help you. Please include a [mcve]. Note that there's no point in creating a new `OnlineOrder` instance and then ignoring it, which is what you're doing in your first snippet.

Comment: I'm a bit fuzzy on the async stuff, but I suspect that ReadAsStringAsync() has not finished reading the string by the time that DeserializeObject gets around to it.   Is there a synchronous ReadAsString call?  If not, I think you need to `await` your `result` before you can assume it will be populated.

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrS: there's no synchronous version of ReadAsString() on the class I'm using, which is HttpContent(). I assumed that adding .Result to the end of ReadAsStringAsync() would work the same way as await, but I'm guessing that's incorrect. I'll try 'await' and see how that works.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I added a sample of the JSON I'm trying to convert. I preserved it for the most part, but altered some info to protect privacy.

Comment: @aaron: I tried await; the order object is still null (see EDIT 2)

Comment: We still don't know what your `OnlineOrder` class looks like.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, in this case, was in the JSON string itself. There was HTML nestled within the JSON string that was not being encoded. Before posting to the server, I used encodeURIComponent(value) in a custom method:

```
    function encodeOrderHtml(order) {
    debugger;
    var o = order;

    //scrub HTML from product options
    if (o && o.serviceDiscount) {
        var sd = o.serviceDiscount;

        if (sd.description !== "" && sd.description !== null) {
            sd.description = encodeURIComponent(sd.description);
        }
        if (sd.descriptionNew !== "" && sd.descriptionNew !== null) {
            sd.descriptionNew = encodeURIComponent(sd.descriptionNew);
        }
        if (sd.displayNameNew !== "" && sd.displayNameNew !== null) {
            sd.displayNameNew = encodeURIComponent(sd.displayNameNew);
        }
        if (sd.name !== "" && sd.name !== null) {
            sd.name = encodeURIComponent(sd.name);
        }
    }
    return o;
}
```

I was able to get valid data to the server by posting the object in the body of the request.