# Json Deserialize Object returns null when called

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net

I'm working with an API that returns a string which looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "835166796775451164",
  "username": "˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞˞",
  "avatar": "x",
  "discriminator": "1391",
  "public_flags": 0,
  "flags": 0,
  "purchased_flags": 2,
  "locale": "en-US",
  "nsfw_allowed": true,
  "mfa_enabled": false,
  "premium_type": 2,
  "email": "x",
  "verified": false,
  "phone": null
}
```

and an object to deserialize this JSON:

```
      public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="id")]
        public string Id { get; set;  }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "discriminator")]

        public string Discriminator { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="phone")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="verfied")]
        public string Verified { get; set; }

    }
```

However when I try to Deserialize the received JSON string to that object and call it, it returns a "null" value. This is my code for deserialization:

```
 if (responseHtml.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = await responseHtml.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                User user= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
            }
```

I also tried making a wrapper from this [Deserialization of JSON.Net returns 'null'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128538/deserialization-of-json-net-returns-null):

```
 public class UserWrapper
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
    }
```

but it also returned a null value

```
 static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await utilities.FetchAccountInformation();
            Models.User user= new Models.User();

            Console.WriteLine(user.Username);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it and just in case somebody faced the same problem I'd like to post a solution on how I managed to solve it. Basically what I did was adding this class that appends additional settings onto a serializer:

```
 internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }
```

and then adding it as a parameter to the DeserializeObject method such as:

```
User user= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json, Converter.Settings);
```

I hope it helps somebody.